# Is there a Lebesgue measurable choice function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

A mapping $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is called a *choice function* if, for any $x, y \ {\rm in}\ \mathbb R$, $f(x)-x \in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ whenever $x-y$ is rational.

My questions is:  Is there a Lebesgue-measurable choice function?

Note: Here I use the equivalence relation for the construction of Vitali sets: x and y are in the same equivalence class iff x-y is rational. So choice functions pick up one element from each equivalence class as its representative value.

Comment: Did you leave something out?  Wouldn't a constant function be a measurable choice function under this definition?

Comment: Yes as stated: for example $f(x)=0$.  But not if you require $f(x)=f(y)$ only if $x-y$ is rational.

Comment: Shouldn't it read: $f(x) = f(y)$ if and only if $x-y$ is rational? Otherwise $f = 0$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the condition that f(x)-x be a rational.  Here I used the equivalence relation for the construction of Vitali sets: x and y are in the same equivalence class iff x-y is rational. My defined choice functions pick up one element from each equivalence class as its representative value.

Comment: No, this is not necesary. If f(x) =f(y), then x-y is rational, i.e., x and y are in the same equivalence class.

Comment: @D.Thomine: I didn't see that part, you are correct of course.

Comment: There is at least no Borel measurable function with this property. Suppose there were a Borel measurable function $f$ with this property. Then it would have a Borel measurable graph $G=\{(x,y):y=f(x)\}$. Now the projection of $G$ on its second coordinate is an analytic set and hence Lebesgue measurable. But it is a Vitali set, contradicting its measurability.

Comment: @Michael: That sounds like an answer to me, you should write it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is measurable. Then $V = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \,:\,f(x) = x\}$ is a measurable representative system for the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ if and only if $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. That is to say, $V$ is a measurable Vitali set, but such a set doesn't exist.

Comment: Your argument is correct, but it might not be obvious why $V$ is measurable. The argument goes like this: Intersect the Graph of $f$ with the diagonal. Now if $(A,\mathcal{A}_1)$ and $(A,\mathcal{A}_2)$ are measurable spaces, then the trace of the diagonal on $A\times A$ endowed with $\mathcal{A}_1\otimes \mathcal{A}_1$ is isomorphic to $(A,\sigma(\mathcal{A}_1\cup\mathcal{A}_2))$ under $(x,x)\mapsto x$. In the given case, the diagonal is isomorphic to the real line with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. Hence, $V$ is measurable.

Comment: @Michael: much simpler: I look at the pre-image of $0$ under the measurable function $g(x) = f(x) - x$.

Comment: *slaps forehead*

Answer (score 3):

There is at least no Borel measurable function with this property. Suppose there were a Borel measurable function $f$ with this property. Then it would have a Borel [measurable graph](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/measurable-graphs/) $G=\{(x,y):y=f(x)\}$. Now the projection of $G$ on its second coordinate is an [analytic set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set#Definition) and hence Lebesgue measurable. But it is a Vitali set, contradicting its measurability.

I don't know how to extend this to Lebesgue measurable functions.